# Formula to replace the "False" with empty cell

Tags: google-sheets

I have been using a google sheet formula which is working fine but the problem is formula presenting "false" where Col"G" data is end.

I have tried with IFERROR and multiple things but could not remove it.

Your help towards the problem will be appreciated.

Sheet Link
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IGSRMfqDODklJdPS4_TIMlIZJSM2JXqf_4pWOGjav4I/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't return empty cell as formula result. But if empty string is enough, add it to the `value_if_false` argument for `IF` function:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(len(G3:G),ROUND(IF(LEN(G3:G),IF(G3:G="Probation",0,IF(F3:F>DATE(2021,1,1)*(G3:G="Confirmed"),(13 - MONTH(DATEVALUE(TEXT(F3:F,"mmm")&" 1"))) * 13/12)),0),""),""))
```

Answer (score 0):

actually, you **CAN** (and should) return empty cell as the formula result

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(G3:G), ROUND(IF(LEN(G3:G),
 IF(G3:G="Probation", 0, 
 IF(F3:F>DATE(2021, 1, 1)*(G3:G="Confirmed"), 
 (13 - MONTH(DATEVALUE(TEXT(F3:F, "mmm")&" 1"))) * 13/12)), 0), ), ))
```